# Proofs for Apéry's accelerated series for $\zeta(3)$

Tags: alternative-proof, riemann-zeta, big-list

Let $\displaystyle \zeta(s)=\sum_{n>1}\frac{1}{n^s}$ denote the Riemann Zeta function for complex $s$ such that $\Re(s)>1$. While proving that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, Roger Apéry found$^1$ the remarkable accelerated series

$$
\zeta(3)=\frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {\binom {2k}{k}k^{3}}}.
$$

His proof of this identity is outlined in Van der Poorten's "[A Proof that Euler Missed...](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)", and a breakdown of this can be found in [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827245/trying-to-prove-that-zeta3-frac52-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k-1). Another, different proof of this identity using creative telescoping can be found in [Jack d'Aurizio's textbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Inspired by another Math.SE post regrouping different proofs for $\displaystyle \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, I became interested in collecting various proofs for this identity above <strike>in hopes of adapting this series to higher zeta constants</strike>. What other proofs are there for this famous identity?

---

$^1$ In fact, it was the Norwegian mathematician Hjortnaes who first found this identity. His paper however has been lost since and the original proof is unfortunately impossible to find on the Internet.

Comment: Why do you write about a "breakdown"?! In the linked question you seemed to agree that no breakdown is present.

Comment: @user I'm not sure how your question is relevant to this post. By "breakdown" I mean "a short overview". Isn't that what the term means?

Comment: "breakdown" = "a failure to work or be successful" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/breakdown)

Comment: @user In this context, I was referring to "C2" in your link, i.e., "*a division of something into smaller parts*"

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarification of the issue.

Comment: @user No, thank you for giving me the opportunity to clarify my statement